# How to delete close elements in java bidimensional array with same values

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, indexing

I changed the request to be clearer. I need to know how to remove a group of neighboring elements that have the same value from a two-dimensional array.

For example if i have the following matrix with dimension 2 rows x 5 columns:

4, 2, 3, 4, 4      row 1

1, 3, 4, 4, 4      row 2

I would like to know how to delete this group of close elements with the same value 4 :

4, 2, 3, ***4***, ***4***   row 1

1, 3, ***4***, ***4***, ***4***   row 2

Not involving elements which don't form a group like the 4 in the top left corner.

I'd like to replace the deleted elements with value -1

Comment: how do you plan on deleting it? replace with zeroes or return a new array with only ```[4,2,3]  [1,3]```? Is it an array or arraylist?

Comment: A group is the same element occurring multiple times in succession?

Comment: This seems to be a "solve my problem"... What's your intension to solve it? Where do you stuck?

Comment: I guess you want to delete the duplicate elements in it

Comment: The examples you have provided show 1D arrays (not 2D as title mentions). Do you mean multiple 1D arrays?

Comment: I changed the request to be clearer. I need to know how to remove a group of neighboring elements that have the same value from a two-dimensional array

Answer (score 1):

say you created the array as:

```
int myArray[] = {4, 2, 3, 4, 4};
```

myArray has a size of 5. The size of an array is fixed.
You can replace them with a 0.

also are you trying to 'remove' a group of the same number?
You can try something like this..

```
for(int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++){
  // if previous element == current element set to 0
  if(myArray[i-1] == myArray[i]){
     myArray[i-1] = 0;
  }
}
myArray[myArray.length] = 0;
```

Comment: I changed the request to be clearer. I need to know how to remove a group of neighboring elements that have the same value from a two-dimensional array.

Comment: i dont think this is a viable solution at all. No idea how this is getting upvoted. ie {4, 2, 4, 4, 3 } --> {4, 2, 0, 4, 0}